# Get name of last two months in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that compares this month's numbers to last month and upper month. The only issue is that colleagues complain about the labelling.

I have used M1 = last month and M2 = upper month, but some people still get it mixed up. I want to put in the actual month instead of M1, M2 and so on. Any ideas would help. This is my code

```
SELECT *,
    CONCAT(FORMAT((current_downloads/M_1)*100,2),'%') AS `M_1_Ratio`,
    CONCAT(FORMAT((current_downloads/M_2)*100,2),'%') AS `M_2_Ratio`
FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) AS current_downloads
    FROM `purchase`
    WHERE date(`purchase`.`timestamp`) >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')) t1
JOIN 
    (SELECT count(*) AS M_1
    FROM `purchase`
    WHERE date(`purchase`.`timestamp`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) t2
JOIN 
(SELECT count(*) AS M_2
FROM `purchase`
WHERE date(`purchase`.`timestamp`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) t3
```

That gives something like this.

[image]

I need the header names to be actual months.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to make variable column names.

Comment: Are you running the query from an application language like PHP or Python? It would probably be easier to change the column headings there instead of SQL.

Comment: None of those two, I'm using Metabase to run this

Comment: I don't know metabase, maybe it has some way to do it. If not, you'll need to write a stored procedure that executes dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a horrible hack (and will only work if your output is purely for presentation), but you could just add another line of data to the table which includes the month names by using a `UNION`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b %y') as Current_Downloads, DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%b %y') as M_1, DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%b %y') as M_2, DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%b %y') as M_1_Ratio, DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%b %y') as M_2_Ratio
UNION ALL
... your query ...
```

This will give you something that looks like this:

```
Current Downloads    M_1     M_2     M_1_Ratio    M_2_Ratio
Mar 18               Feb 18  Jan 18  Feb 18       Jan 18
12,168               12,121  13,345  100.39%      91.18%
```

Comment: I think this temporarily solves my issue with team members knowing what month each column represents. Thank you