# Add a empty row into select SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, row

Is it possible to add a dummy row in the select clause which represents as a header to the results that are returned.
The header should be part of the SQL query results.

```
Name|Address|Phone Numer
XYZ|City name|1233457890
```

The second  row is the sql result and first one the header.
I already have the header string constructed which is dynamic.

Comment: maybe with  UNION

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565293/get-name-of-last-two-months-in-sql/49565709#49565709) but note that it will attempt to cast all the data in the rest of your query to the types of the values in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query.

```
select 'Name' as "Name", 'Address' as "Address", 'Phone Number' as "Phone Number" from dual
union all
select Name, Address, "Phone Number" from yourtable
```